# Georeferencing a GeoTIFF using with RasterIO

Tags: python, georeferencing, rasterio, ground-control, coregistration

I am trying to Co-register a raster using Ground Control Points w.r.t. another raster using RasterIO. I have written a PoC, but having a bit of difficulty in measuring the quality of the final transformed raster. I do not have any ground truth transformed raster to verify it against but using QGIS tool and GDAL APIs are giving completely different and seemingly off results

I have manually identified few common points in both the rasters and now trying to setup the whole pipeline for the co-registration.

Terminology:
Query Raster: Raster to be co-registered
Reference Raster: Reference raster to co-register to

Following are my GCP-pairs (pixel values):

```
[[query_x, query_y], [reference_x, reference_y]]  
[[4891, 2922], [4701, 2731]],  
[[4902, 2898], [4710, 2703]],  
[[4826, 1998], [4631, 1795]],  
[[4551, 1293], [4360, 1102]],  
[[4605, 733], [4413, 537]]
```

My rasters are in WSG84 co-ordinate system (crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'})

So for doing the transformation, I am projecting my reference pixels to the WSG84 co-ordinates

```
reference_longitude, reference_latitude = reference_raster_dataset.xy(reference_y, reference_x)
```

and initialising the GCPs

```
rasterio.control.GroundControlPoint(row=query_y, col=query_x, x=<reference_longitude>, y=<reference_latitude>)
```

After this, am using

```
 transform = rasterio.transform.from_gcps(<list of GCPs>)
```

to get the Affine transform and re-projecting each band using the transform computed above.

So, my final doubts are:

1. Is my Ground Control Point format and initialisation correct?
2. Is there any metrics that I can use to verify the quality of the co-registration
3. Is the flow correct, because I am not able to find any working code flow etc, so just followed and implemented the theoretical guides to the co-registration process

Comment: It would be useful if you posted an answer of what you figured out. You're right that this is not well documented.